# Improper integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha}\ln x}{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{4} \frac{\sin(\pi \alpha/2)}{\cos^2(\pi \alpha/2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, self-learning, polylogarithm

> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha}\ln x}{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{4} \frac{\sin(\pi \alpha/2)}{\cos^2(\pi \alpha/2)}$$
>   where $0 < \alpha < 1$.

Answer: When i put this term in my integral calculator, it gave me very lengthy answer involving polylogarithm functions.

Comment: Have you searched in this site about this integral?

Comment: @Nosrati, I didn't search in this site about this integral. But if this is a duplicate question, please provide the link of this question's answer available in this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\alpha\log(x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\alpha}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\frac12\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\frac{\alpha-1}2}}{x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\frac12\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+\alpha}2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-\alpha}2\right)}{\Gamma(1)}\tag3\\
&=\frac\pi2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\csc\left(\pi\frac{1-\alpha}2\right)\tag4\\
&=\frac\pi2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\sec\left(\frac{\pi\alpha}2\right)\tag5\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4\tan\left(\frac{\pi\alpha}2\right)\sec\left(\frac{\pi\alpha}2\right)\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}x^\alpha=x^\alpha\log(x)$
$(2)$: substitute $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$
$(3)$: [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$(4)$: [Euler Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)
$(5)$: trigonometric identity
$(6)$: evaluate the derivative

Comment: How did you compute (2)? You substitute x by $\sqrt{x}$.So I get $\frac12\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{x^\frac{\alpha}{2}}{x+1}dx$ But your term in (2) is different?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{d}\sqrt{x}$? You got the $\frac12$, but forgot the $x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: I already got the answers to this question from you and one other member of this site correctly satisfying all my queries. Then what is the use of making it off-topic and put on hold?

Answer (score 4):

By substitution $x=\tan t$
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^a}{1+x^2}\ dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^at\ dt$$
then using dear [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$$I(a)=\dfrac12\Gamma\left(\dfrac{a+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{-a+1}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{2\sin\pi\dfrac{1-a}{2}}=\dfrac{\pi}{2\cos\dfrac{a\pi}{2}}$$
by [Reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) the desired integral is 
$$\dfrac{d}{da}I(a)=\color{blue}{\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}\dfrac{\sin\frac{a\pi}{2}}{\cos^2\frac{a\pi}{2}}}$$

Comment: How did you compute the first equation? I never found it in the list of trigonometric identities?

Comment: It is in fact no trigonometric identity but just the substitution $x=\tan(t)$. From hereon you will get the upper as well as the lower border of integration. Further note that the derivative of $x=\tan(t)$ can be written as $dt=\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ due the derivative of the tangent function.

Comment: @Nosrati, is $I(a)$ regularised incomplete beta function? why it is multiplied by$\frac12$?

Comment: See the link, fourth formula of _Properties_.

Comment: @Nosrati, But it is $I_x(1,b)=1-(1-x)^b$. Now what is x and what is b? I assume that it is a derivative of $\tan^{\frac{a-1}{2}}{(x)}$

Comment: Is $\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^a}{1+x^2}\ dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^at\ dt$ clear?

Comment: @Nosrati, Yes, You have substituted x=tan(t).

Comment: So $$I(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^at\ dt=\dfrac12\left(2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^at\cos^{-a}t\ dt\right)$$

Comment: @Nosrati, That's the very good math trick.